# Scrapy - How to get duplicate request referer

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-settings

When I turn on `DUPEFILTER_DEBUG`, I got:

> 2016-09-21 01:48:29 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: http://www.example.org/example.html>

The problem is, I need to know the duplicate request's referrer to debug the code. How can I debug the referrer?

Comment: Try implementing your own visited log, in memory or in file, by for example using a yielded links pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be a *custom filter* based on the built-in `RFPDupeFilter` filter:

```
from scrapy.dupefilters import RFPDupeFilter

class MyDupeFilter(RFPDupeFilter):
    def log(self, request, spider):
        self.logger.debug(request.headers.get("REFERER"), extra={'spider': spider})
        super(MyDupeFilter, self).log(request, spider)
```

Don't forget to set the [`DUPEFILTER_CLASS` setting](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=filter#dupefilter-class) to point to your custom class.

(not tested)